# Does the DoubleClick Google Analytics integration support Event Tracking?

Tags: google-analytics, event-tracking

Does anyone know if the DoubleClick google analytics integration (dc.js) supports Google Event Tracking?

Asked previously about Content Experiments (it doesn't), but figured this was a different question.

Comment: Yes, the DoubleClick (dc.js) does support event tracking, social interactions, and custom variables.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can assure you DC.js does support event tracking, and all other major reporting suits (e-commerce etc.), provided you set them up correctly.